# Canvas not rendering image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a basic isometric engine in JavaScript but with the following code the image isn't rendering, I'm just getting a blank white canvas. Why is that? Is it because the image source is a URL? I've been trying to figure this out for an hour now haha.

```js
(function(isometric) {
  var map = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
  ];

  var tileGraphics = [];

  function loadImg() {
    var tgToLoad = ['http://jsiso.com/tutorials/images/land.png'];
    var tgLoaded = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < tgToLoad.length; i++) {
      tileGraphics[i] = new Image(25, 52);
      tileGraphics[i].src = tgToLoad[i];

      tileGraphics[i].onload = function() {
        tgLoaded++;
        
        if (tgLoaded === tgToLoad.length) {
          drawMap();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function drawMap() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');

    var tileW = 25;
    var tileH = 52;

    var mapX = 76;
    var mapY = 52;

    var drawTile;

    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; i++) {
        drawTile = map[i][j];
        ctx.drawImage(tileGraphics[drawTile], (i - j) * tileH + mapX, (i + j) * tileH / 2 + mapY);
      }
    }
  }

  function init() {
    isometric.removeEventListener('load', init);
    loadImg();
  }

  isometric.addEventListener('load', init, false);
})(this);
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

I'm following [this tutorial](http://jsiso.com/tutorials/2014/10/26/isometric-engine-basics.html).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)' <-- have you tried to run it before?

Comment: Because your `map` variable is an `Array` of `Array`s of the number `1`, the line `drawTile = map[i][j]` sets `drawTile` to the value `1`. Unfortunatly, the `tileGraphics` variable only has a single item at index position `0`. Therefor, the method `drawImage` receives `undefined` instead of the image, because `drawTile` points to the wrong index position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, there are a few problems.

1. You have one image in your array (index 0) and you are trying to load image (index 1). You need to subtract 1 from your index to access the correct image.
2. Your `j` inner-for-loop is incrementing `i++`

Here is the [link to the tutorial](http://jsiso.com/tutorials/2014/10/26/isometric-engine-basics.html) for others.

```js
var TILE_WIDTH = 25, TILE_HEIGHT = 52;
var map = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 2, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, 2, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0] // Skip drawing the southern quadant.
];
var tileGraphics = loadImages([
  'http://jsiso.com/tutorials/images/land.png',
  'http://jsiso.com/tutorials/images/water.png'
], function() {
  drawMap(document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d'), drawTile);
});

function loadImages(arr, callback) {
  var result = [];
  var loadCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    loadImage(arr[i], TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, function() {
      result.push(this); // Add image
      loadCount++;
      if (loadCount === arr.length) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
  return result;
}

function loadImage(src, width, height, callback) {
  var img = new Image(width, height);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = callback;
  return img;
}

function drawMap(ctx, tileDrawingFn) {
  var width = ctx.canvas.width;
  var height = ctx.canvas.height;
  var xOffset = ((width - TILE_WIDTH) / 2) - (TILE_WIDTH / 2);
  var yOffset = ((height - TILE_HEIGHT) / 2) - (TILE_HEIGHT / 2);
  for (var row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < map[row].length; col++) {  // not row++
      tileDrawingFn(ctx, row, col, xOffset, yOffset, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }
  }
}

function drawTile(ctx, row, col, x, y, width, height) {
  var index = map[row][col] - 1; // Skip tile 0 aka index -1
  if (index > -1) {
    var image = tileGraphics[index]; // Subtract 1 to get image 0
    ctx.drawImage(image, (row - col) * width + x, (row + col) * height / 4 + y); // vs. height/2
  }
}
```

```css
#main { border: thin solid black; background: #444; }
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="256" height="192"></canvas>
```